# Why the content at 0000:0000 changed after the cmd at 0483:0117 executed?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

Before:

```
AX = B160;
DS = 0000;
next_cmd = 0483:0117 = ADD AX, [0004]; 

it shows DS:0004 = 60EF;
it means when the_next_cmd executed, AX must be B160+60EF=124F
```

After:

```
the content at 0000:0000 changed!
and AX=maybe a wrong HEX
```

[image: Screenshots]

I did try again and again, reset the content and execute again the cmd, the result is always like that. I don't know why. Could someone explain this?

Comment: You're in real mode, so `add ax, [4]` shouldn't fault, so that isn't letting other code run and change memory.  Is your debugger running inside DOSBox?  If so, then it might be modifying the IVT (interrupt vector table which starts at `0000:0000`).  But if your single-stepping is done by the emulator itself transparent to the guest machine, that instruction only reads memory and updates AX.  (Assuming TF isn't set in the guest, otherwise the CPU will take an exception after each instruction.)

Comment: Are you using debugger? `0000:0004` contains Trap interrupt vector, debugger uses it.

Comment: The dwords that changed are #1 and #3 counting from zero at `0000:0000`, the vectors for interrupt numbers 1 and 3.  Those are both used by debuggers; 1 is the interrupt number for TF single-stepping, 3 is the interrupt number for `int3` software breakpoints.  So I'd guess you are running a debugger inside the guest machine.

Comment: This is in part a bug in the original Microsoft Debug, it sets the two vectors but never resets them. My fork [MSDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/msdebug.zip) and my advanced debugger [lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug) based on FreeDOS Debug/X will both restore the int 1 and int 3 handlers in the IVT. (Debuggable lDebug as well as the MSDebug build will both reset the vectors after every T/P/G command, non-debuggable lDebug will reset them when quitting the debugger.)